# Should tenants be deleted? What about historical reporting?

Tags: database, saas

I am creating a multi-tenant SaaS app with a shared-db, shared-schema.  Here is my question: What are good policies for deleting tenants?  Here are some of my thoughts...

If I delete a tenant and all its associated data:

1. I will lose my ability to report off that data
2. I will get rid of data that I don't need (a good thing, except for reporting)
3. I will free up things like subdomain names that other tenants might want

Does anyone have any best practices or suggestions for this subject?

Piet

Answer (score 2):

Don't report off of production, report off of a data warehouse.  Roll the warehouse over periodically into different generations, then you can purge production to match those ages.